# Is authenticated data showing on webpage when not logged in Django/vue

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, nuxt.js

I have an app with Django and Nuxt js that uses express sessions and redis to store session tokens.

I'm trying to add a page with data from my backend that will only be displayed if user is authenticated. 
For some reason it's not working. The data is displayed when I'm logged out even after multiple refreshes.

Here's my code.

**Django/Views.py**

```
class OrdersViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                    viewsets.GenericViewSet,
                    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin
                    ):

    queryset = Orders.objects.all().order_by('-time_stamp')
    serializer_class = OrdersSerializer   
    permission_classes= [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

**webpage.hmtl**

```
<template>
  <div class="course-list-row">
    <table>
      <thead id="header-fixed">
        <th scope="col">Time Stamp</th>
      </thead>
    </table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="row in orders" :key="row.id">
        <td style="width:5px">{{ row.time_stamp }}</td>
        <td style="width:5px">{{ row.event_name }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ app }) {
    try {
      const res = await app.$axios.get("api/orders/");
      return {
        orders: res.data.results,
        error: false
      };
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error", e);
      return {
        orders: [],
        error: true
      };
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**store.js**

```
export default {
  state: () => ({
    loggedIn: false,
    user: null
  }),
  actions: {
    async nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req, app }) {
      console.log('nuxtServerInit', req.session.authToken)
      if (req.session.authToken) {
        const data = await app.$axios.$get('/api/auth/me/')
        commit('SET_USER', data)
      } else {
        commit('SET_USER', null)
      }
    },
    async login ({ commit }, creds) {
      await this.$axios.$post('/auth/login/', creds)
      const data = await this.$axios.$get('/api/auth/me/')
      commit('SET_USER', data)
    },
    logout ({ commit }) {
      this.$axios.$post('/auth/logout/')
      commit('SET_USER', null)
    },
    load_runner ({ commit }, runner) {
      commit('SET_RUNNER', runner)
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_USER (state, user) {
      if (user) {
        state.loggedIn = true
        state.user = user
      } else {
        state.loggedIn = false
        state.user = null
      }
    },
    SET_RUNNER (state, runner) {
      if (runner) {
        state.filtered = true
        state.runner = runner
      } else {
        state.filtered = false
        state.runner = null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Djangosettings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
    ),

    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated", 
    ),

    "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": "rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination",
        "PAGE_SIZE": 100,
}
```

Comment: How are you logging out?

Comment: I'm logging out using the logout button on webpage. The project is with docker and when i rebuild it, it's the same issue

Comment: @IainShelvington I see. I had a freelancer work on project so he may of made changes:(

Comment: On logout you don't seem to be removing `req.session.authToken`? Maybe this is still being sent with the requests